# Fixing code for R program..another if loop

Tags: r, if-statement

The problem is that there are times that my data has no numbers greater than or equal to 5 and less than 80 or there are times when I only have one observation so I can't perform a t.test. How do I use an if statement inside my loop so that if it doesn't get any value between 5 to 80 or only has one observation, it just uses `NA` and doesn't perform the t.test?

Comment: Please provide a sample data set and desired output for this set. Doing so allows contributors to quickly validate results and compare solutions.

Comment: Your problem is that lengths of empty dataframes are not zero. Test for `NROW(.) < 2`.

Answer (score 2):

DWin is correct.  Types matter in R and length doesn't always work the way you expect with dataframes.  You should be able to use `nrow` or `NROW` to get the "length".  If all else fails, you can use `try` but that always makes me feel dirty.

To know for sure, though, please provide an example as requested by Matthew.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a "try" block like this inside the lapply.  Initialize the result to NA, and it will only assign the t.test result if it doesn't run into any errors.

```
data2 <- lapply(1:length(m), function(i) {
         res = NA
         try({ 
             #you can put your other constraints here
             if(length(m[[i]][[5]]) > 1) {
                 res = t.test(data1$Value,m[[i]][[5]])
             }
         }, silent=T)
         res
 })
```